# Audio doesn't work on a Dell Vostro 3550 laptop

Tags: sound, dell

I have installed ubuntu 10.4.3 on dell vostro 3550 laptop.

I have installed all files related to audio but audio is not working on this laptop.

Answer (score 0):

From a reference on the ubuntuforums: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1906905 some people have solved audio problems on this make of laptop by doing the following:

Add this line to /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

```
options snd-hda-intel model=dell-vostro-3500
```

Then, restart alsa by enter the following in a terminal session

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

If it is possible for you to do so it may be worth considering updating to 11.04 or 11.10, the Dell Vostro 3550 has been certified to work with both of these releases: [Ubuntu Certification](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/models?form.search_text=Dell%20vostro%203550&search=Search&form.hardware_category=DESKTOP&form.hardware_category=LAPTOP&form.hardware_category=NETBOOK&form.hardware_category=SERVER&form.hardware_release=Any&form.level=ANY)